# Convert image with mogrify and output it to variable

Tags: php, shell, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert a `bmp` to `jpg` with mogrify.The jpg should then be store in a variable.

Here is my attempt thus far

```
$jpg_content = shell_exec("gm mogrify -format jpg ". escapeshellarg($image) . " && cat " . escapeshellarg($image)."2>&1");
```

However `$jpg_content` is null

**Edit**

Suppose that `$image` is `/var/www/website.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699218`

```
shell_exec("gm mogrify -format jpg ". escapeshellarg($image));
$jpg_content = file_get_contents($image.'.jpg');
```

After mogify is done then it should have created the jpg but its not the case here.The `tmp` directory is writable and thus its not a permission issue.

Comment: Why not just execute `mogrify` and then read in the content with `file_get_contents`?

Comment: @MattRaines i wanted to do it as efficiently as possible

Comment: In what sense is reading the file using `cat` more efficient?

Comment: @MattRaines I was assuming that `file_get_contents` would be slower than `cat` but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590017/php-performance-file-get-contents-vs-readfile-and-cat prove me wrong

Comment: Interesting. But will those 4 extra milliseconds make or break your website either way? If not, I'd just go with whatever's most readable.

Comment: @MattRaines check edit

Comment: Why are you writing to disk at all? Why not `$content=shell_exec("gm convert a.bmp jpg:-");`

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you post this as an answer so that i can accept it.If its not too much to ask could you please take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838561/content-instead-of-path-in-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid writing to disk at all by telling GraphicsMagick to write a JPEG on its *stdout* and picking that up into a PHP variable like this:

```
$content=shell_exec("gm convert image.bmp jpg:-");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you thought should `&& ...` do?

Remove the `" && cat` and all behind it.

Comment: My attempt is based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685871/save-shell-output-to-variable and i already tried what you suggest and it didn't work

Comment: I see, you could've added that info to the question. Then the problem might be the last comment to the answer in your referenced question: "You have to use the -format option to set to jpg. Mogrify will then output to the same filename where the .bmp file extension.is replaced by .jpg" - you did the first but then read back the original bmp, you would have to read back the file with the modified jpg extension?